# Path prefix for Swagger in NestJs

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I use Swagger and NestJs. The deployed project has a prefix `/api`, but locally has not.
There is no global prefix set and it's fully app hosting feature to add a prefix.
Is it possible to set up the prefix just only in the doc?

I tried to use `.setBasePath` method, but it does not influence and there is no any info there.
I expect that the prefix will be set in the swagger doc depends on the provided option, like `.setBasePath(environment === 'local' ? '' : '/api')` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
`.setBasePath()` does not work any more.
Instead it's possible to use `.addServer` method of the `DocumentBuilder` class
like

```
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
  .addServer('/api')
  .build();
```